# Finding solution to partial differential equation using separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have been given the following question with sample answers

> Find the solution to Laplace’s equation $∇^2 u=0 $ in the unit square $D=[[x,y] ∶0≤x≤1,0≤y≤1]$ subject to the boundary condition $u=0$ on $x=0$,$x=1$ and $u=sin⁡(πx)$ on $y=0$,$y=1$

A part of the solution is attached below:

> [image: Blockquote]

In the solution we apply the boundary condition for the whole PDE on to the $F(x)$ equation to elimate or keep $A$ or $B$.

My questions in how we can do this since the boundary coindition is for the whole PDE $u=F(x)G(y)$ and not just for $F(x)$.

For example a certain value of $A$ and $B$ 'could' solve the boudnary condition $u=0$ for $x=0,1$ when $u=F(x)G(y)$ but not solve when we only use $F(x)$

Is using the boundary condition for one variable first a valid method to solve partial differential equation is all situations?

Answer (score 1):

The boundary conditions on the left and right edges of the squares is that $u(0,y)=F(0) \, G(y)=0$ and $u(1,y)=F(1) \, G(y)=0$ for **all** $y \in [0,1]$. Since $F$ and $G$ are assumed to not be identically zero (since that would just give the useless solution $u \equiv 0$), there is some $y_0 \in [0,1]$ where $G(y_0) \neq 0$. So the only way that those boundary conditions can hold for $y=y_0$ is that $F(0)=F(1)=0$.